Ellipsis text for mui text area
I am working with MUI TextareaAutosize.
Here is what I am trying to do I have set min and max rows as 4, given fixed width and height. I want to let the user type more than 4 rows, however when the focus is out I want to last row i.e 4th to end with ellipsis i.e (...) and when user clicks the textArea i.e focused in then the content should be scrollable.
Here is what I have tried
const StyledTextArea = styled(TextareaAutosize)(({ theme }) => ({
  fontFamily: 'inter',
  color: '#616161',
  minHeight: '120px',
  maxHeight: '120px',
  overflow: 'hidden',
  overflowY: 'auto',
  textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
  width: '327px',
  borderRadius: '4px',
  backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  resize: 'none',
  ...theme.typography.body,
  border: '1px solid #9E9E9E40',
  lineHeight: '24px',
  padding: theme.spacing(8),
  '&:focus-visible': {
    border: '1px solid #2196F3',
    outline: 'none'
  },
  '&:active': {
    border: '1px solid #2196F3'
  },
  '&:disabled': {
    border: '1px solid #9E9E9E40',
    backgroundColor: '#E0E0E0'
  },
  '&:hover:not(:focus-visible):not(:disabled)': {
    border: '1px solid #9E9E9E40'
  }
}))


<StyledTextArea
        ref={ref}
        id={id}
        {...props}
        maxRows={4}
        minRows={4}
      />

This is what I am trying to achieve, i.e the below image


Unfortunatly, text-overflow Applies to block container elements only. Textarea is a replaced element : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element . Try a contenteditable div instead ;)
